# Como ativar a bateria de economia?

Tags: android

Como faço para ativar a economia de bateria?

Vou desenvolver um aplicativo que monitore a bateria, e que, quando chegar em um determinado percentual de bateria, a economia de bateria seja ativa de forma automática.

Comment: Não seria o caso de pesquisar na documentação do Android? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

Comment: Ativar a economia de bateria quer dizer disconectar as redes moveis, reduzir brilho. É isso?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, acho que ele fala sobre ativar o recurso de economia de bateria nativo do sistema, que já é habilitado automaticamente ao chegar em determianda porcentagem. No caso, acredito que ele precisa apenas que o app dele tenha capacidade de manusear o valor definido no recurso de economia de bateria padrão do sistema.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo: Sim, hoje no Android 7.0 (puro), tem um recurso nas configurações dele que, quando a bateria chega em 15%, ele ativa sozinho a economia de bateria (ele não desliga redes moveis, nem reduz o brilho, só desliga animações e reduz o processamento), eu queria ter "controle" sobre como ativar e desativar esse recurso programando.

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira, exatamente isso!

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira Pesquisei no stack em inglês e no google, porém, não encontrei nada que me auxiliasse de forma concisa.

Comment: Não me parece que isso seja possível. A classe [BatteryManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) apenas permite monitorizar os níveis e estado de carregamento da bateria.

Comment: Veja isso. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234502/programmatically-enable-disable-battery-saver-mode

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Já tinha chegado a esse stack também, porém ele diz que só é possível em "on rooted devices".

Comment: Já viu se existe algum app que faça isso que você pretende? Eu não programo pra mobile, mas levando pro lado da lógica, acho que é inviável. O recurso de economia de energia do Android é nada mais que um app que já vem com o sistema, e sendo um app, você não consegue mexer nas definições dele através de outro app, não sem fazer alguma gambiarra no aparelho. Isso seria uma tremenda falha de segurança.

Comment: Eu acredito que isso esteja uma camanda abaixo do app, a nivel de sistema mesmo, entao acho que voce nao consegue forcar o modo de economia nao. Em um aprelho com root (como disseram) acredito que seja possivel ja que o root "libera" acesso a algumas coisas antes inacessiveis. Sem contar que ia virar a maior bagunca se qualquer app pudesse induzir esse modo

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode ativar o recurso de `economia de bateria` programaticamente. Isto porque o próprio android não tem uma função nativa que faça isso e/ou não permite. Você só pode fazer isso se o **dispositivo** for `rooteado`. E, mesmo assim, não tem uma função que faça isso, você teria que alterar um padrão de configuração do dispositivo, teria que inserir um valor no arquivo de configuração dele.

> Alternativas

Como você quer fazer um aplicativo que vai gerenciar o uso de energia do dispositivo, sua única saída é criar **o seu próprio sistema de economia de bateria**.

Para fazer isso, você vai ter que listar todos os processos do dispositivo ou todos os aplicativos em execução, então, você vai gerenciar esses aplicativos, vai fechar eles quando for preciso, executar novamente quando não for mais preciso fecha-los e etc.

Deixarei um link abaixo que te ajudará a fazer o que eu disse acima.

Fonte: [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html)